# Pagenumbering with romanbar compatible to hyperref

Tags: hyperref, page-numbering, roman-numerals

Is there a good way to use the package `romanbar` also for page numbering, with compatibility to `hyperref`?

The following example works without `hyperref` but not with it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,ngerman]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{romanbar,hyperref}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\Roman@bar{\Roman{page}}}%
\makeatother
\jobname

\end{document}
```

It would even better to activate this with `\pagenumbering{Roman}`.

This is just an example. I know that changing `\thepage` in that way is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified the usage by converting [answer 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120066/pagenumbering-with-romanbar-compatible-to-hyperref/120656#120656) into a LaTeX package. See [`romanbarpagenumber` on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/romanbarpagenumber).

```
\usepackage{romanbarpagenumber}
% And after \begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
```

Answer (score 5):

Page labels are only text strings, thus additional bars of package `romanbar` are not supported. but they can easily be disabled:

```
\usepackage{romanbar,hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\Roman@bar\@firstofone}
```

(Instead of `\@firstofone` also `\@empty` or `\relax` can be used.)

Comment: Good to know that there is a macro like `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` …

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I just found out that I can also redefined `\pagemark` which is a bit more elegant.

I use this to set `\pagemark` when ever the `\pagenumbering` is expanded.

```
\let\pagenumberingRaw\pagenumbering\relax%
\renewcommand{\pagenumbering}[1]{%
  \pagenumberingRaw{#1}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{Roman}}{%
    %\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{\Roman@bar{\Roman{page}}}% not added by \pageref.
    \renewcommand*{\thepage}{\Roman@bar{\Roman{page}}}%
  }{
    %\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{\thepage}%
  }
}
```

Edit: After all redefining `\thepage` seams to be the best way because it is also used by `\pageref`. Thanks again Heiko Oberdiek.

Comment: `\Roman@bar` will not be added for Roman page numbers referenced via `\pageref`.